# Contar cantidad de datos ingresados

Tags: python

mucho gusto, me encuentro aprendiendo Python pero estoy teniendo problemas al momento de contar la cantidad de datos que he ingresado a la terminal. Tengo un problema que me solicita lo siguiente: *Escribe un programa que lea del teclado números enteros y los vaya contando y sumando. El programa se debe detener cuando la suma de los números leídos sea 1000 o más.* Hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
suma = 0
while suma < 1000:
    valor = float(input())
    suma = suma + valor
    if suma >= 1000:
        print(f"suma = {suma}")
```

Intenté crear listas para contar los valores que he ingresado pero en verdad no se muy bien como funcionan jaja. Agradecería mucho me orientaran para este caso.

Comment: Agrega un contador 'ingresos'. Sumale 1 en cada iteración.

Comment: Debajo de tu variable suma pon `contador =0` y luego debajo de tu `if` (no adentro) pones `contador +=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español.

Se trata de contar y sumar los números que ingresa el usuario. En principio el programa que has mostrado haría solo la parte de sumar, aunque tiene un par de cosas que conviene mejorar:

1. Como el enunciado habla de recibir números **enteros**, deben convertirse con `int` y no con `float`, que es para números de punto flotante.
2. La condición de que la suma sea mayor o igual que 1000 la estás comprobando dos veces, lo que es redundante. En este caso no generaría ningún problema, pero hay que tener cuidado con ese tipo de cosas porque pueden dar lugar a errores en programas más complejos.

Además de esto, faltaría contar los números. Para ello bastaría tener una variable contador a la que sumemos 1 cada vez que el usuario introduce un nuevo número.

Aplicando todos estos puntos, el programa quedaría así:

```
suma = 0
contador = 0
while suma < 1000:
    valor = int(input())
    suma += valor
    contador += 1
print(f"suma = {suma}")
print(f"total entradas = {contador}")
```

Observa que las dos últimas líneas no tienen indentación, y por tanto se hallan fuera del bucle `while`, y solo se ejecutarán cuando la condición `suma < 1000` deje de cumplirse.